# jQuery img alt attribute with variable at the end

Tags: jquery, alt

I am trying to add a variable at the end of an `alt` attribute to make all alts on a page different. How is that possible.

This code works

```
$('.MyClassName img:not([alt])').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
```

But this code needs changing - it does not work!

```
var x = 1;
$('.rte img:not([alt])').attr('alt', 'Alternative text' + $x);
```

Comment: `$x` != `x`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he would also need a loop (unless he wants the same `alt` value for every element that matches the selector.

Comment: Assuming that there's more than 1 `img`, you're correct. However the OP states the first line works correctly so this would appear to not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, declared variable is `x` not `$x`. Either declare variable with `$` or update `attr()` to use defined variable. Following declares variable in different ways.

NOTE: below code will try to update all elements with `MyClassName` css class. Update selector as per your needs.

```js
$('.MyClassName').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
console.log($('.MyClassName').attr('alt'));

var x = 1;
$('.MyClassName').attr('alt', 'Alternative text' + x);
console.log($('.MyClassName').attr('alt'));

var $x = '$1';
$('.MyClassName').attr('alt', 'Alternative text' + $x);
console.log($('.MyClassName').attr('alt'));

// won't work as $y not defined
var y = 1;
$('.MyClassName').attr('alt', 'Alternative text' + $y);
console.log($('.MyClassName').attr('alt'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="MyClassName" alt="">
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would assign the same value to the `alt` attribute of all the things classed as `.MyClassName`

Comment: @JeromyFrench yes, this is just for demo purpose. OP already has some structure in the question but haven't posted the HTML markup. added a note in the answer

Comment: Fair...but OP did state "to make all alts on a page different". I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/a/65149644/1430996 is what OP has in mind.

Comment: That looks good, too. but `x` should be updated within loop otherwise it will also give the same result as mine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this within a loop. Try using [the `each()` function](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var x = 1;
$('.rte img:not([alt])')
    .each(function(index){
        /* do something with x here, or use `index` if you just want an incrementing counter */
        $(this).attr('alt', 'Alternative text' + x);
    });
```

Comment: Just FYI you don't need `each()` for this: ```$('.rte img:not([alt])').attr('alt', (i) => `Alternative text ${i}`);```